# After launching anaconda Prompt I get an error The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, anaconda

After launching anaconda prompt I get following errors. I already add Path variables to following paths since im not installed Anaconda in "C" drive.

The system cannot find the path specified.

Failed to create temp directory "C:\Users\A&E\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-"
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSkbR.png)

Please Help to solve this thank you.

Comment: can you navigate to that path from your file manager? Also, do you have space on your C drive

Comment: To which path, I can navigate to the Temp

Comment: Did you try my solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is the special characters in your username. It should work using a username without special characters (ex: AandE instead of A&E). You can refer here for more information: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9757.